# CamelContext loads, but route definitions are empty

Tags: java, spring, groovy, apache-camel, applicationcontext

I'm trying to manually load `CamelContext` from `applicationContext.xml` file which looks like this:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xsi:schemaLocation="                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd                                                                                                                                                                    
                                 http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

  <camelContext id="camelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
      <from uri="direct:a"/>
      <to uri="direct:b"/>
    </route>

    <route>
      <from uri="direct:b"/>
      <to uri="direct:c"/>
    </route>

    <route>
      <from uri="direct:c"/>
      <to uri="mock:direct:c"/>
    </route>
  </camelContext>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

</beans:beans>
```

While loading I'm using this snippets (groovy code):

```
def xmlBeans = applicationContext.getBeanFactory()
new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(xmlBeans).loadBeanDefinitions('test/integration/resources/applicationContext.xml')
def camelContext = applicationContext.getBean("camelContext")
camelContext.start();
println "Route definitions: " + camelContext.routeDefinitions
println "Routes: " + camelContext.routes
```

Everything loads just fine, but `routes` and `routeDefinitions` are empty ;(

The output is:

```
Routes definitions: []
Routes: []
```

What I'm doing wrong? Or what I've missed to do?

**UPDATE 1**

After some research I've found the following. If I modify my XML file and change nested tag to some invalid value (e.g. replace `<from>` with `<from1>`) I'm getting error immediatelly.
However, if I change endpoint URI to some invalid value (e.g. `mock:direct:c` replace with `mock_XXX:direct:c`) - no errors are thrown.

I believe that Spring's validation of schema runs, however, camel validation of routes does not.

**UPDATE 2**

When I replace `camelContext.start()` with `applicationContext.start()` nothing changes.

**UPDATE 3**

After some suggestions I've changed my code like this:

```
    final Main main = new Main();
    main.setApplicationContextUri("test/integration/resources/applicationContext.xml");
    main.start();

    def ctx = main.applicationContext

    ctx.beanDefinitionNames.each { name ->
      if(name == 'camelContext'){
        def cctx = ctx.getBean(name);
        println "\nRD:" + cctx.routeDefinitions // <!-- this prints routes
      }
    }

    ctx.beanDefinitionNames.each { name ->                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      def beanDef = ctx.beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(name);
      applicationContext.registerBeanDefinition(name, beanDef)
    }

    // TODO remove this snippets                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    def camelContext = applicationContext.getBean("camelContext")
    applicationContext.start();
    camelContext.start();
    println "Route definitions: " + camelContext.routeDefinitions //<!-- this does not
    println "Routes: " + camelContext.routes //<!-- this does not
```

First output prints routes as expected. Second output does not. As following:

```
RD:[Route(a)[[From[direct:a]] -> [To[direct:b]]], Route(b)[[From[direct:b]] -> [To[direct:c]]], Route(c)[[From[direct:c]] -> [To[mock:direct:c]]]]
Route definitions: []
Routes: []
```

It seems that route definitions somehow not initialized or loaded or whatever thus it's just empty.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `camelContext.routes`? Not sure...

Comment: From http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/CamelContext.html#getRoutes()

Comment: Routes shows actual route instances, routeDefinitions shows only definitions.

Comment: I've changed the code snippets, plz check

Answer (score 0):

You need to start CamelContext to have it load its routes. It appears as you just load the spring bean definitions. And that does not cause CamelContext to trigger its loading of its routes etc. So this is expected that its empty.

Comment: camelContext.start() does not help. I've changed the code snippets, plz check

Comment: You need to start Spring, eg applicationContext.start() which should also start Camel.

Comment: I believe my applicationContext is started somewhere else. However, tried your suggestion - does not work. I'll put the update to my problem now.

Comment: I've updated my problem defintion once again. Please, check. As you see camel context is started. applicationContext either.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I never tried to start a Camel Spring context via Groovy. In Java, I use `org.apache.camel.spring.Main` for testing:

```
 final Main main = new Main();
 main.setApplicationContextUri("test/integration/resources/applicationContext.xml"); // use wildcards if needed
 main.start();
```

Perhaps this may be an alternative for you to solve your problem.

Comment: No, this is not the case as I aleady have applicationContext and want just `inject` my camelContext into it.

Answer (score 0):

While this does not directly solve your problem, the camel debug output often helps. In spring boot, enabling it is done by setting

```
logging.level.org.apache.camel=DEBUG
```

in your application.properties file. [An official alternative is](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/tracer.html)

```
camel.springboot.tracing = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue that I noticed after my attempt to use "**AdviceWith**" failed with

> **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot advice route as there are no routes**

```
AdviceWith.adviceWith(camelContext, "seda:my-original-route", a ->
        a.replaceFromWith("direct:my-replacement-route)
);
```

It turned out, that I was missing `@EnableAutoConfiguration` on my test.

So this is the complete set of annotations that was required:

```
@UseAdviceWith
@CamelSpringBootTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@MockEndpointsAndSkip("direct:my-finishing-route")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SomeRequiredBean.class})
public abstract class MyBaseTest{

}
```